# Como obtener el token de usuario para peticiones http si estoy usando nextAuth?

Tags: reactjs, next

He creado una sesión con next 13.4.19 y next auth 4.23.1, también tengo un middleware para proteger mis rutas, todo esto funciona bien, cuando logeo un usuario obtengo una sesión y un token de sesión (next-auth.session-token), pero necesito hacer mas peticiones http con el ytoken de usuario no con el token de sesión,  la pregunta es como podría obtener ese token

Tengo en la configuracion de NetxAuth la peticion http que logea el usuario, y obtengo informacion del usuario, inclutyendo el token, necesito obtener ese token en un middleware para enviarl en el header para hacer mas peticiones http, como podría hacerlo?

Esta es mi primera aplicaciòn con next, podrian explicarme como lograr esto?, gracias por la ayuda

**En /src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts**

Aqui configuro el credential provider y el usuario usando la peticiòn http (este seeria el token que necesito para las otras peticiones http)

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { _AUTH } from "@/app/services/shared/endpoints";

export const handler = NextAuth({
session: { strategy: "jwt" },
providers: [
CredentialsProvider({
async authorize(credentials, req) {
const res = await fetch(_AUTH._AUTH_LOGIN, {
method: "POST",
body: JSON.stringify({ user: { ...credentials } }),
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
});
if (res.status === 200) {
const user = await res.json();
//console.log("HERE  THE USER TOKEN I NEED TO GET IN A MIDDLEWARE ================>",user.token)
if (!user) {
return;
} else {
return user;
}
}
},
}),
],
pages: {
signIn: "/login",
},
callbacks: {
async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
return `/empresa/mis-empresas`
}
}
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

**En middleware.ts**

Aqui obtengo el token de sesion, para proteger mis rutas quiero crear un middleware aqui         para e

Here I get the session token, to protect my routes, I want to create a middleware here to add headers and send user token for every http request.

```
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

  const session = req.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token")
  if(session === undefined){
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/`, req.url));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/empresa/mis-empresas',
  ]
}
```